# Mirror second monitor in a window

Tags: duplicate-display

I am looking for a program that will allow me to display my second monitor in a window on my first monitor.

The setup I have is: I have a projector hooked up to my computer and the projector is acting like a second monitor (not a mirror of the first). The projector screen is quite far away from where the computer is and when I am moving content around on it from that far away, it is difficult to tell whether it is in the correct spot on the screen.

It would be nice to have a mirror copy of what is being displayed on the projector in a resizable window on my main monitor to make it easier to place content and resize objects.

Things it should to have:

- Linux / Windows (Computer is dual boot)
- Hopefully free or low cost
- Windows mirroring second monitor needs to be resizable on the computer monitor
- Not require any hardware video splitters